# TypeScriptOutFile on CompileTypeScript target in msbuild project

Tags: msbuild, typescript

I want to have a combined js file from typescript sources on build. My *.csproj file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" />

  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <ProjectGuid>{83A2324A-201F-4CE8-A57B-16770214E3B2}</ProjectGuid>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>1.4</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">12.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>False</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
    <TypeScriptOutFile>..\bin\app.js</TypeScriptOutFile>
    <TypeScriptSourceMap>true</TypeScriptSourceMap>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <TypeScriptCompile Include="src\TypeScriptCompilerPlugin.ts" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="CompileTypeScript">
  </Target>

</Project>
```

The problem: on build VS generate file src\TypeScriptCompilerPlugin.js, not ..\bin\app.js...

Answer (score 3):

Solution: import **Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props** must be at the top of the file, but import **Microsoft.TypeScript.targets** must be at the bottom.

Comment: I saw this answer and thought "no way" but after trying it this did solve my problem. Thanks for posting the answer after you found it!